# How can I set the milestone size in ms-project

Tags: ms-project

How do I change the milestone sign in the gantt chart to be larger?

Answer (score 4):

Following works in MS Project 2003 (I know it's an old version, don't blame me, blame the company :-) )

Right click on the milestone icon and click 'format bar'
You get a popup screen in which you can select the icon you want to use.

I don't think it possible to make it bigger though, only change color, shape or type...
Personally, I don't think it makes any sense to make it bigger, as it is the whole Gantt chart you zoom in/out... not a specific symbol...

Perhaps in later versions of MS Project, this is possible...

Comment: Thanks kenneth, it's funny 2003 was the last version I've used ... Any how the answer to my question is to right click the gantt chart select the layout and there you can chane the "bar height" ... I really can't remember if this feature existed in 2003 but I am almost sure it did.

Answer (score 0):

In 2010 go to Format / Layout, then increase the 'Bar Height' figure